# Can't get inside my for loop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate over the variable `pieces`, but somehow it is not triggering. In the function below, `pieces.length` turns 4, but `piecesNew` turns `[]` - moreover `console.log(i)` is never reached.

What is happening?

```
self.reworkPieces = function(pieces) {

        var piecesNew = [];

        console.log(pieces.length)

        for (var i; i <= pieces.length; i++) {

            console.log(i)

            piecesNew[i] = {
                c: pieces[i].r,
                r: pieces[i].c,
                p: i
            }

        }

        console.log(piecesNew)

        return piecesNew;

    };
```

Comment: set your `i` to 0...

Comment: What is the need of `angularjs` tag here?

Comment: removed angularjs tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`undefined` is not *less than* or *greater than* any number.

```
var i; // undefined
i < 10; // false
i > 10; // false
```

You simply need to make sure `i` is equal to `0`.

You also want `i` to never be equal to `pieces.length` so use `<` instead of `<=` (the last index of an array is always `length - 1`, e.g. an array of length 3 has indexes 0, 1 and 2 – the first index is always 0, not 1)

So:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    ...
```

Comment: More accurately, any comparison of a number to undefined is false.

Comment: @DanielCook: Not true, `undefined != 0` is `true` if you treat that as a comparison

Answer (score 3):

define value for variable i, `var i = 0`

```
self.reworkPieces = function(pieces) {

        var piecesNew = [];

        console.log(pieces.length)

        for (var i = 0; i <= pieces.length; i++) {

            console.log(i)

            piecesNew[i] = {
                c: pieces[i].r,
                r: pieces[i].c,
                p: i
            }

        }

        console.log(piecesNew)

        return piecesNew;

    };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.reworkPieces = function(pieces) {

    var piecesNew = [];

    console.log(pieces.length)

    for (var i = 0; i <= pieces.length; i++) {

        console.log(i)

        piecesNew[i] = {
            c: pieces[i].r,
            r: pieces[i].c,
            p: i
        }

    }

    console.log(piecesNew)

    return piecesNew;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
 for (var i; i <= pieces.length; i++)
```

To:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize var i = 0 initially then it will work

```
self.reworkPieces = function(pieces) {

            var piecesNew = [];

            console.log(pieces.length)

            for (var i = 0; i <= pieces.length - 1; i++) {

                console.log(i)

                piecesNew[i] = {
                    c: pieces[i].r,
                    r: pieces[i].c,
                    p: i
                }

            }

            console.log(piecesNew)

            return piecesNew;

        };
```

Comment: this for (var i = 0; i <= pieces.length - 1; i++) loop only iterate the array element from zero index to last index